# ¿Utilizando SendGrid V1 y C# como elimino un email de las listas sin saber el tipo?

Tags: c#, .net

Utilizando SendMail V1 y C# de la siguiente manera puedo saber si un email esta en la lista de **bounces** y obtengo información:

```
var client = new SendGridClient(this.apiKey);
var response = client.RequestAsync(method: SendGridClient.Method.GET, urlPath: "suppression/bounces/" + email).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

Ahora quiero eliminar un solo correo de las listas sin importar de que tipo sea.
¿Como armo la petición para hacer esa eliminación?

Answer (score 1):

Si usas la API de SendGrid

[sendgrid-csharp](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp)

podrias hacerlo, analiza el ejemplo que esta en github

[suppression](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/examples/suppression/suppression.cs)

```
// Delete a bounce
// DELETE /suppression/bounces/{email}

string queryParams = @"{
  'email_address': 'example@example.com'
}";
var email = "test_url_param";
var response = await client.RequestAsync(method: SendGridClient.Method.DELETE, urlPath: "suppression/bounces/" + email, queryParams: queryParams);
Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
Console.WriteLine(response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

en los ejemplos hay varios casos no se si el que puse es justo lo que buscas, pero creo que se aproxima ya que realiza el DELETE, sino analiza los otros, pero veo que en algunso casos primero realiza el GET para luego armar el mensaje del DELETE

Comment: Eso funciona pero para el tipo o la lista de "bounces". Cuando llegan los correos a SendGrid pueden llegar de varios tipos o en varias listas: bounces, Invalids, Blocks... entre otros.
El problema es que para cada tipo toca cambiar la url y necesito consultar un correo independiente de la lista. No quiero consultar lista por lista, lo que quiero es una sola petición y el tipo no me importa, lo que me importa es que este reportado en las listas de SendGrid.
Gracias por la respuesta @Leandro Tuttini

Comment: mm pero la consulta de las listas depende de como ester armado el servicio, cda lista entiendo es una queue diferente conceptualmente en el mail, piensalo como si estuvieras usando el outlook, para ver los enviados presionas un lugar diferente a la carpeta de spam (no esta todo mezclado), quizas debas consultar cada lista por separado

Comment: Si pues eso es lo que veo, por eso pregunto si hay alguna forma de no hacer varias peticiones. En un sistema de alta concurrencia se multiplicarían las peticiones.